# Disable QSlider's valueChanged on keyboard arrow keys

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, mousewheel, qslider

How can I disable QSlider's  emitting SIGNAL valueChanged on keyboard arrows and mouseWheel scroll. By setting

```
    ui->horizontalSlider->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

the keyboards arrows keys are not emitting signals.

How can I do the same for mouse wheel scroll?
I don't want to reimplement my custom Slider class from QSlider.
Am asking for any work around or api, so that I can disable the keyboard and mouse wheel scroll responding to qslider.

The main intention is to avoid sending signals on every valueChange. So I have implemented the following and it's working fine

```
on_horizontalSlider_sliderReleased()
on_horizontalSlider_sliderPressed()
```

based on bool flag updated in these 2 slots,

```
on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int)
```

is doing the required operation...like after slider released, value is being added in the required application.

Request to provide approaches, examples for the work around.

Comment: thats not really possible. If the value changes, that signal is emitted. Thats the definition of it. You already proposed the solution yourself: Use the pressed/released signals to react to the value instead of using the valueChanged signal.

Comment: Yes..it's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CBlockWheelEV: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CBlockWheelEV( QObject* parent ): QObject( parent ) {}
    bool eventFilter(QObject * pObject, QEvent * pEvent) override
    {
        if ( pEvent->type() == QEvent::Wheel )
        {
            qDebug() << pObject << pEvent;
            return true; // if return false - Scroll was unlocking
        }
        return false;
    }
};

...
ui->sldTest->installEventFilter( new CBlockWheelEV( ui->sldTest ) );
...
```

You can use EventFilter to block emitting signals ValueChanged from QSlider by wheel rotating. But if you want some special behavior - you need control additional options in you EventFilter. EventFilter can manage many behavior of object without subclassing it.

Comment: I'll implement this and let you know...but a concern is that, if it disables the mouseWheel button click..then we may be have to change some major thing.

Comment: I think mouse button press have another event type like:
    QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick
    QEvent::MouseButtonPress
    QEvent::MouseButtonRelease

Comment: A simpler resource management idea would be to have the following method: `static installOn(QObject *o) { Q_ASSERT(o->thread() && qApp && o->thread() == qApp->thread()); static CBlockWheelEv blocker; o->installEventFilter(&blocker); }` The filter is quite useless in non-gui threads, and you don't need more than one instance of it.